# Whenever I save a product I get "Something went wrong" and in the report I get this error

Tags: magento2, products, reports, save, magento-2.1.1

I got this in my error report:

```
> a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:5172:"#0
> /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()
> #1 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(258): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->read()
> #2 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(166): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('review_listing')
> #3 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144):
> Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('review_listing')
> #4 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(30):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('review_listing')
> #5 /data/web/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(24):
> Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()
> #6 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102):
> Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()
> #7 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226):
> Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #8 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74):
> Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #9 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70):
> Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
> Array)
> #10 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...',
> 'dispatch',
> Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor),
> Array, 'adminAuthentica...')
> #11 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #12 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67):
> Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor),
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #13 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...',
> 'dispatch',
> Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor),
> Array, 'adminMassaction...')
> #14 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33):
> Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #15 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142):
> Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor),
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #16 /data/web/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(52):
> Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> Array, Array)
> #17 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55):
> Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #18 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74):
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #19 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70):
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
> Array)
> #20 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
> Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...',
> 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
> Array, 'install')
> #21 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69):
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #22 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142):
> Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor),
> Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #23 /data/web/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26):
> Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> Array, Array)
> #24 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
> #25 /data/web/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
> #26 /data/web/magento2/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
> #27 {main}";s:3:"url";s:137:"/admin_1km1d8/mui/index/render/key/73a0c1d284f6f6ee033441e272c363477606a15d7cf3b90c0ac3988cddd4814f/?namespace=review_listing&isAjax=true";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Who knows what this is?

## edit

I've checked the permissions and did as the links said but the problems stays. And it can write in it because it did so before.

Comment: I get the same error when simply viewing a product in the admin, not even trying to save it. My permissions are also set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue with your permissions.
Check the link below to see if everything is fine:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

If you have command prompt access, could you pleaae try to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and share the output with us? It should show us where the problem is...

Answer (score 1):

`var/generation` is not writable.

`var`, `app/etc` and `pub/static` should be writable by web server.
Like this http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6704

I had the problem too and it's because Magento_Review module is disabled (enable it in Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced). Just enable it for now, until the problem is solved, probably on the new version of Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your terminal to **enable all** modules and to do the deploy again:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;

mage module:enable --all

mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```